# Flickr image effect with fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having trouble displaying some images with different height and width,

I want them to be in a layout like flickr.com galleries,

All images there have a fixed height and the width adjusts to that height to keep the original image ratio, and filling up the container..
Im looking for a way to do that or a plugin that helps me achieve that goal.. But i haven't find one.

I have used masonry.js but that one is for the opposite.. A fixed width and the height adjusts to that width to maintain image ratio.

Thanks in advance for any help that you guys can give me.

Edit:
This is the effect i'd like to achieve, all containing rows have same height, so all images have same height,

[image]

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot or drawing, that might be helpful. If you are wanting all same heights, you could make a fixed height class and make overflow-y: hidden. Like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nv32edw5/

Comment: Sounds like Bin-packing problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415169/n-fold-partition-of-an-array-with-equal-sum-in-each-partition and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem